# High Sierra (Mac OS 10.14.6): Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm currently having a problem installing Cocoapods 
When i tried to do **sudo gem install cocoapod**s in terminal i get thesis error
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. 
  i can't solve it.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo6po.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mojave (Mac OS 10.14.6): Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227103/mojave-mac-os-10-14-6-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Comment: I know the other question has not been answered, but you asked the same question twice. Remove this question or the other question.